# type-cast rule in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

So known fact: `(byte)1 ^ (byte)1` results in an `int` (per the spec).

Can someone explain to me why the following is possible without explicit cast (from `int` to `byte`)? `byte myByte = (byte)1 ^ (byte)1`

The following, on the other hand, is not allowed:

`int i = 0; byte b = i;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
(byte)1 ^ (byte)1
```

is a constant expression ([JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)), which is known to be in the range of `byte`. You can therefore implicitly convert it to `byte` in an assignment context ([JLS 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

If it *weren't* a constant expression (e.g. if one of those values were a variable instead) then the assignment would fail.